# Error using ==> check at 28 Error evaluating parameter 'Value' in 'buck_ssavg/A1':

Tags: simulink, matlab

Error using ==> check at 28
    Error evaluating parameter 'Value' in 'buck_ssavg/A1': Undefined function or variable 'A1'.
    Error using ==> check at 28
    Error evaluating parameter 'Value' in 'buck_ssavg/A2': Undefined function or variable 'A2'.
    Error using ==> check at 28
    Error evaluating parameter 'Value' in 'buck_ssavg/B1': Undefined function or variable 'B1'.
    Error using ==> check at 28
    Error evaluating parameter 'Value' in 'buck_ssavg/B2': Undefined function or variable 'B2'.

M file programme:

```
    clc;clear all;close all;
tic
syms s
%converter parameters
Vin =10;
R=5;
L=0.5e-3;
C=300e-06;



T=100e-6;
%controller parameter
% Vref=5;VU=3;VL=0;k1=1;
% Kp=0.12
K1=280;
%simulation parameters
Tstart=0.0;Tstop=0.15;
Max_step=2e-07;Min_step=1e-08;
Rel_tol=1e-4;Abs_tol=1e-6;

warning off 
% xInitial=[0.7597  5.0007  0.0150];


for D=0.5:0.1:1

    sim('buck_ssavg')
%   xinitial=xFinal;
% xInitial=[0.7597  5.0007  0.0150];
% Xinitial=xFinal;



A1=[0 -1/L 0;1/C -1/(R*C) 0; 0 -K1 0];
A2=[0 -1/L 0;1/C -1/(R*C) 0; 0 -K1 0];
B1=[1/L 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 K1];
B2=[0 0 0; 0 0 0;0 0 K1];
Aa=D*A1+(1-D)*A2;
Ba=D*B1+(1-D)*B2;
Ca=(A1-A2)*X +(B1-B2)*Vin;
end

I=eye(3,3);
Gv=inv(s*I-Aa)*Ca
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your model `buck_ssavg` is using the variables `A1`, `A2`, etc... except you define them in the workspace only after you have run the model with the `sim` command, so when you are running the model, those variables do not exist yet. Try running the `sim` command after you have defined `A1`, `A2`, etc... (i.e. just before the `end` statement).